# Compare two dataframes and filter the matched values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Previous question: [Pandas Compare two dataframes and determine the matched values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884056/pandas-compare-two-dataframes-and-determine-the-matched-values)

I have two dataframes:

```
print(a)

    ID                              Value
0   AA12 101 BB101 CC01 DD06        1
1   AA12 101 BB101 CC01 DD06        2
2   AA11 102 BB101 CC01 2341 DD07   2
3   AA10 202 BB101 CC01 3451 DD09   3
4   AA13 103 BB101 CC02 1231        4
5   AA14 203 BB101 CC02 4561        5
print(b)

    ID                              Value
0   AA12 101 BB101 CC01 1351 DD06   1
1   AA12 101 BB101 CC01 1351 DD06   2
2   AA11 102 BB101 CC01 DD07        2
3   AA10 202 BB101 CC01 3451 DD09   3
4   AA13 103 BB101 CC02             4
5   AA14 203 BB101 CC02 4561        6
```

**Desired output**:

```
     ID                              Value   ID Matched?   Value Matched?
0    AA12 101 BB101 CC01 DD06        1       Yes           Yes 
1    AA12 101 BB101 CC01 DD06        2       Yes           Yes 
2    AA11 102 BB101 CC01 2341 DD07   2       Yes           Yes
3    AA10 202 BB101 CC01 3451 DD09   3       Yes           Yes
4    AA13 103 BB101 CC02 1231        4       No            Yes
5    AA14 203 BB101 CC02 4561        5       Yes           No
```

Here's the code written by @MaxU from the previous post:

```
pd.merge(a.assign(x=a.ID.str.split().apply(sorted).str.join(' ')),
             b.assign(x=b.ID.str.split().apply(sorted).str.join(' ')),
             on=['x','Value'],
             how='outer',
             indicator=True)
```

**What I want to achieve**:

- If either dataframes do not contain four-digit item from ['ID']
  (i.e. 2341, 3451), I want to exclude it from the matching process.
- If Same ID appears more than once, they can have different values on 
  ['Value'].

The result of this code is [here](http://pastebin.com/rzKvvvVi). Unfortunately, it doesn't achieve the desired result. Only Index 3 gets matched. I was tweaking the code but couldn't figure out the next step.

Thanks you so much for your time and consideration!

Comment: the entire dataframe must have no 4-digit in ID? or you want to exclude only rows not having 4-digit pattern (like index 0 and 1 in your example)?

Comment: If either a.ID or b.ID does not contain 4-digit, I want to get rid of it from the ID on those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

first let's split and stack ID column in both DFs:

```
In [248]: d1 = df1.set_index('Value').ID.str.split(expand=True).stack().to_frame('ID').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'idx'})
     ...: d2 = df2.set_index('Value').ID.str.split(expand=True).stack().to_frame('ID').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'idx'})

In [249]: d1
Out[249]:
    Value  idx     ID
0       1    0   AA12
1       1    1    101
2       1    2  BB101
3       1    3   CC01
4       1    4   DD06
5       2    0   AA12
6       2    1    101
7       2    2  BB101
8       2    3   CC01
9       2    4   DD06
10      2    0   AA11
11      2    1    102
12      2    2  BB101
13      2    3   CC01
14      2    4   2341
15      2    5   DD07
16      3    0   AA10
17      3    1    202
18      3    2  BB101
19      3    3   CC01
20      3    4   3451
21      3    5   DD09
22      4    0   AA13
23      4    1    103
24      4    2  BB101
25      4    3   CC02
26      4    4   1231
27      5    0   AA14
28      5    1    203
29      5    2  BB101
30      5    3   CC02
31      5    4   4561

In [250]: d2
Out[250]:
    Value  idx     ID
0       1    0   AA12
1       1    1    101
2       1    2  BB101
3       1    3   CC01
4       1    4   1351
5       1    5   DD06
6       2    0   AA12
7       2    1    101
8       2    2  BB101
9       2    3   CC01
10      2    4   1351
11      2    5   DD06
12      2    0   AA11
13      2    1    102
14      2    2  BB101
15      2    3   CC01
16      2    4   DD07
17      3    0   AA10
18      3    1    202
19      3    2  BB101
20      3    3   CC01
21      3    4   3451
22      3    5   DD09
23      4    0   AA13
24      4    1    103
25      4    2  BB101
26      4    3   CC02
27      6    0   AA14
28      6    1    203
29      6    2  BB101
30      6    3   CC02
31      6    4   4561
```

now we can search for `'not matched'` IDs:

```
In [251]: no_match_idx = d1.loc[~d1.ID.isin(d2.ID), 'idx'].unique()

In [252]: no_match_idx
Out[252]: array([4], dtype=int64)

In [253]: df1['Matched_ID'] = ~df1.index.isin(no_match_idx)
     ...: df1['Matched_Value'] = df1.Value.isin(df2.Value)
```

Result:

```
In [254]: df1
Out[254]:
                              ID  Value Matched_ID Matched_Value
0       AA12 101 BB101 CC01 DD06      1       True          True
1       AA12 101 BB101 CC01 DD06      2       True          True
2  AA11 102 BB101 CC01 2341 DD07      2       True          True
3  AA10 202 BB101 CC01 3451 DD09      3       True          True
4       AA13 103 BB101 CC02 1231      4      False          True
5       AA14 203 BB101 CC02 4561      5       True         False
```

Comment: Best solution ever! I learned about stacking as well! Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

Comment: @comprocho, glad i could help :-)