# How to compare two dataframes and filter the different data?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently two dataframes that must be the same, but are of different sizes. How do I compare the two Dataframes, to find the data that are different using pandas?

I couldn't use `df_control.eq()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [14, 22], 'col2': [32, 22]})
df.eq(df2)
```

Compare two series

```
Output:
col1    col2
0   False   False
1   False   True
```

I practically want to compare the two dataframes with a large amount of data and filter the rows that are different, for data validation

Expected

```
col1 col2  Verify
1      3    False
2      4    False
14     32   False
22     22   True
```

Comment: Where is the `14` coming from?

Comment: @mozway updated, my expected result link[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032326/compare-two-dataframes-and-filter-the-matched-values)

Comment: So you don't really want to compare `df` and `df2`, but rather `col1` and `col2`?

Comment: @mozway I would like to compare two series as proposed in this solution
link[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032326/compare-two-dataframes-and-filter-the-matched-values)

Comment: OK, so the question is not correct. It would be great to update for clarity to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
result = pd.concat([df, df2])
ar = result.to_numpy()
result['Verify'] = (ar[:, [0]] == ar).all(axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```py
   col1  col2  Verify
0     1     3   False
1     2     4   False
0    14    32   False
1    22    22    True
```